# Truth set of $\forall x \in X P(x)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assuming $X = \{ x_0, \space x_1, \space x_2... x_n\}$, then  $\forall x \in X P(x)$ is equal to $P(x_0) \land P(x_1) \land P(x_2)...P(x_n)$  (STATEMENT 1).

According to Vellemen in *How to prove it?*, $\forall x \in X P(x)$ is the same $\forall x[x \in X \rightarrow P(x)]$. If we expand the last formula, we get: $[x_0 \in X \rightarrow P(x_0)] \land [x_1 \in X \rightarrow P(x_1)] \land [x_2 \in X \rightarrow P(x_2)]...[x_n \in X \rightarrow P(x_n)]$ (STATEMENT 2).

I can't see why STATEMENT 1 and 2 are logically equivalent. In fact, STATEMENT 1 implies STATEMENT 2, but not the contrary. Any help?

Comment: Assuming $X = \{ x_0, \space x_1, \space x_2... x_n\}$, both statements are equivalent since the antecedents in STATEMENT 2 will all be true, allowing you to reduce the implications to their consequent. Only without the assumption they would not be equivalent, but then STATEMENT 1 would look differently.

Comment: And how would STATEMENT 1 look like, considering the possibility of false antecedents?

Comment: If any $x_i \in X$ would be false, $X$ would not contain $x_i$, so I assume that $P(x_i)$ would not be part of the conjunction in STATEMENT 1. Or am I wrong on how you constructed STATEMENT 1?

Comment: I constructed Statement 1 based on the usual understanding of the universal quantifier as an expansion of logical conjunctions. I am not entirely sure if the statement is correct or complete.

Comment: Maybe it becomes more clear if you consider any $y \notin X$. It would not be expanded to another conjunct in STATEMENT 1, but considering that $y$ is part of the universe where we prove statements in, it would lead to another conjunct $y \in X \rightarrow P(y)$ in STATEMENT 2. But this implication is always true because the antecedent is false. The conjuncts in STATEMENT 2 do need the implication because they range over all objects, not only the elements of $X$.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the way we should read Statement 1. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Read the proof I gave you when you asked the same question for countable sets. @TylerD007